# As a system app, kill another process, by package name

Tags: android

I'm developing a watchdog system service on android.
In case I detect that some foreground app is blocked/halted I want to force restart of the app.

I've already tried kill background app, with no success (as i'm trying to kill a foreground app).
also, via exec(adb shell su killall com.package.name) crashes with no permission, as i'm "just" system, not rooted device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a way.

You can get the pid name by

```
private int getAppUid(String packageName){
    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pidsTask = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(int i = 0; i < pidsTask.size(); i++) {
        if (pidsTask.get(i).processName.equals(packageName)){
            return pidsTask.get(i).uid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

after that, you can just kill it with

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(pUID);
```

works for my android 7 device.